# Does this code establish a database connection?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a very amateur level PHP coder, trying to make sense of someone else's code, written for a Windows environment that I am adapting for Linux. Most of the code works fine now except for the database functionality. Hours of work later and I suspect the code fails to ever establish a link with the database, but it's waay beyond my pay grade to understand what the original author was trying to do here, much less find the fault. I'm hoping someone out there can see the wood for the trees here.

First I have the config.php file which looks like this:

```
<?php
    $GLOBALS["CONFIG"] = array(
                                //Config for mysql server
                                "mysql" => array(
                                                "server"    => "localhost",
                                                "user"      => "myuser",
                                                "pass"      => "mypassword",
                                                "db"        => "visitorboard"
                                            )
                            );
?>
```

I have checked all the credentials by writing a simple connection test file that i do understand, and the credentials are correct.

Then, in the main file I see lines tha include the following:

```
//Database
    $MySql = new MySql($GLOBALS["CONFIG"]["mysql"]["user"], $GLOBALS["CONFIG"]["mysql"]["pass"], $GLOBALS["CONFIG"]["mysql"]["db"], $GLOBALS["CONFIG"]["mysql"]["server"]);
```

followed almost immediately by...

```
$Exists = $MySql->query("SELECT * FROM ip_timezones WHERE ip = md5({0}) LIMIT 1", array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]))->fetch();
```

Now, as far as I can tell, none of these SQL transactions achieve anything at all. Nothing seems to be read and definitely nothig ever written (where it tries to later). Then i thought 'this doesn't seem to use any of the old proceedural connect commands I understand, or (as far as i see) any of the object-oriented stuff I don't understand - not in establising that initial connection anyway'. Whatever is happening here sure doesn't appear to be working. Can anyone with more experience shine a light on the thinking in this code and tell me - is it connecting, or does it never even try?
Thank you.

Comment: yes its connecting.. look for the `MySql` class and you see the connection within the constructor or such, it may extend a class which is providing the ->query methods (cant tell without seeing). the `$Exists = ..` is in fact reading from the db as its chained with `->fetch()`. All this would error if it's not working, presuming you have error reporting enabled, if not check your log or turn it on.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to  [Lawrence Cherone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/lawrence-cherone) for answering this question. This code does indeed connect to a database. My inexperience led me not to see that 'MySql' (in the "new MySql(..." call) was in fact a class, and within that class the actual database connection was established. Thank you for pointing out the technique used here!